# Vue js prototype function to rerender template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a very basic key-based translation system since our system doesn't have to be as expansive as something like vuei18n. I'm simply loading a json with a key and each key has four translations. About a hundred items in total. Now; I'm using a seperate Translator window component that I link to Vue like this;

```
Vue.prototype.translate = function(key){
   window.addEventListener('switchedLanguage', function(event) { 
        console.log(event.detail);
        return window.translator.getTranslation(key);
    });
    return window.translator.getTranslation(key);
}
```

and in order to render them in the templates I do the following:

```
{{ translate('key') }}
```

I understand that connecting scripts like a translator directly to the window isn't the best of practices, but is what's working in the application right now.

The thinking behind it is that when the language is changed within the translator, it will try to get back the key. While this technically works, in the application I am not seeing the keys get re-rendered to the different language. I've been deep down the rabbit hole now and don't seem to get a clear answer why except for the fact that it's not bound to the data model. But for some of the components, they can have up to fifteen keys or more depending on input. It's not feasible to store all the keys in the data model of each component since that will, in my view, unnecessarily clutter the data model.

So, what I've tried so far is the following:

- Use a filter with the key as an input (this results in Vue freaking the hell out because it can't resolve the filter since it isn't able to find the translator through Window.translator)
- Reload the entire window (while working, very ugly solution since it takes the user back to the main screen)

Comment: Obviously this won't work because there is nothing that is causing your translate function to run again after you change your language. You are simply binding to the prototype object. You are not setting up two-way binding like this. Simply using a getter with a Vuex store module to hold the translations for all your components would probably suffice in this scenario. An alternative to this would be to manually force a re-render with an event hooked up to whatever you are using to switch language.

Comment: It might be obvious to you however I am not that well versed in Vue yet. If you read what I'm asking; It's asking about whether it is possible or not and if not a possible alternative to the issue.

The manual forcing of a re-render using vm.$forceUpdate() did not work either. It was succesfully called; but the components stayed using the same language. If rerouting from a different point in the application to the next it would work. I will look into the vuex store module.

Comment: Can't help you much further without a code example, perhaps prep a simple example?